# How to right-align element from overflow text

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Right-align from overflow text instead of its parent.

[image]

Here's my sample code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jjno6n

Comment: let me know your actual expectation. give me few more details on the alignment to help yoi

Answer (score 0):

Further analysis, your CSS has an issue,

Change your CSS like the below

```
.CheckoutSteps {
    /* display: inline-flex; */
    /* align-items: center; */
    align-items: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
 }
```

Output

[image]

I would strongly recommend you to read this article

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Comment: Thanks Kannan but the requirement is actually, it should be right-aligned.

Comment: Oops ok, right alignment mean right side - shopping, payment and confirmation one by one? Right aligned or u need similar like you showed in above screenshot?

Comment: The whole steps 1, 2 & 3 should be moved a little to the left so that it should be something like this (see link below) but without a constant value (e.g. margin-left: 25px).
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qfhfx2

Answer (score 0):

I've created a hack for now LOL!

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.checkMargin();
}

checkMargin() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const paddingRight =
      (document.querySelector(
        ".CheckoutSteps .Step:last-child .StepLabel span"
      ).clientWidth - 40) / 2;
    document.querySelector(
      ".CheckoutSteps"
    ).style.paddingRight = `${paddingRight}px`;
  }, 200);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Is this what you want to achieve my friend? The problem is that the container has a fixed size, I don't know if that is a requirement or just making the circle "circle".

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-le2wxp

Comment: Almost but as you can see, it brakes the grey line. If step is active (red) then line is connected, if not then it shouldn't touch the step (circle). And distances between steps should be constant.